# SQL Column 2 change from NULL to NOT NULL if the value of Column 1 is 1

Tags: sql, triggers, constraints

I have an sql table with let say col1 and col2, i want to create a constraint or a trigger (whatever works) such that col2 should change from NULL to Not Null if and only if the value entered in col1 is 1.

The point is, i want to make a col2 field mandatory if col1 is set to 1 otherwise remain optional.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_YourTable] CHECK  (([col1]=(1) AND      [col2] IS NOT NULL OR [col1]<>(1)))
GO
```

If you want to exclude empty string too then:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_YourTable] CHECK  (([col1]=(1) AND    (  [col2] IS NOT NULL AND [col2] <> '') OR [col1]<>(1)))
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, after testing the query above, the column still allows NULL, can we use NOT EMPTY instead?

Comment: If col1 has a value of 1 it doesn't allow null to col2. If col1 has any other value, then null is an option. Isn't that the requirement?

Comment: just finished implementing it, it works, i had to insert data on all col2 cells, ADD the constraints and then remove data on col2 which col1 is not 1.

Answer (score 4):

You mention SQL Server in a comment

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
Col1 INT,
Col2 VARCHAR(25) NULL,
CONSTRAINT ck_foo CHECK (NOT (Col1 = 1 AND Col2 IS NULL))
);
```

would disallow `NULL` as stated in the question. To also disallow empty strings the constraint definition could be

```
CONSTRAINT ck_foo CHECK (NOT (Col1 = 1 AND ISNULL(Col2,'') = ''))
```

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply, i have tried but its still allow NULL Values, i have read somewhere that NOT NULL and NOT EMPTY are different things in SQL Server, can it be the reason the statement fails?

Comment: @user2587302 - It doesn't allow `NULL` values. `INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES(1,NULL)` fails. What are you actually trying to prevent? Both `NULL` and empty string?

Comment: Mostly empty string, will be filling a form in an application, i would like it not to save if the conditions above are not fulfilled.